# Interop User Control In MSAccess

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I've created a simple ActiveX user control from the VB6 Interop UserControl Template (as a C# developer who hasn't touched VB in years was a shock to the system!!!). The control loads an image from a URL and then allows the user to zoom in and out of the image.

All works fine and have tested it using TstCon, but when I try and add it to an Access 2013 form the control isn't listed. I know it can be done as I've read on other forums it can, but nobody seems to say how. Can anyone shed any light on what I might be missing in order for it to load in Access?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You said VB6 in both your title and your question, yet you tagged it with VB.NET?

Comment: Have you tried registering the DLL?

Comment: Yes I've tried registering the dll using regasm, seems to work fine but no control in Access

Comment: Visual Vincent - project type is VB6 Interop UserControl, language in there is VB.Net, apologies for any confusion caused!!!